# outputting text to a particular line in file using <fstream> header

Tags: c++, fstream

How can i write some text to a file's particular line using `<fstream>` header? Is there any function to do that? Thank you.

Comment: No, files don't work that way.

Comment: You mean i can only add text to the end of a file?

Comment: no, you can add text in the middle or the beginning of a file. checkmy answer.

Comment: you cn write your own function... (not complicated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really do that because the line you write might be longer than then one that exists.  So you would clobber a line or have to rewrite the whole file.

If the lines are all exactly the same length, you could do binary writing.

[Edit:  the following line was mistakenly added, it's for .NET only]

If you can, use File.ReadAllLines and File.WriteAllLines.

Comment: What header file is `File.ReadAllLines` defined in?

Comment: @jweyrich: It wasn't really a joke... I honestly don't understand how this answers the question, yet it was accepted.

Comment: @CodyGray: oh sorry. I thought you knew `File::ReadAllLines` was .NET and purposely asked "What header file" as a way to notify the author about that mistake. Me neither. It addresses only part of the problem, and just conceptually.

Comment: Oops, my bad.  Maybe my post was marked as the answer because of the explanation.

Comment: @Steve Wellens : this is wrong. in fact, it is possible. check my answer.

Comment: @eharvest : recheck my answer.

Comment: i know there is no existing function to call to do that automatically but it is possible to do even if you dont want to replace a line with the same enght : Loki Astari wrote a code. and i write two algorithms to do that... that is why i sai your answer is wrong, because it is possible to do with a developper own developed function.

Comment: your answer seems to mean you cannot do it, but you explain vaguely that it is possible... yeah, it is a way to express the answer. i agree that it is not immediat and that is no cool. it is not difficult to add this possibility in kernels so manipulating files will be effictive.

Comment: I'll repeat the pertinent parts of my answer here:  "So you would clobber a line or have to rewrite the whole file.  If the lines are all exactly the same length, you could do binary writing."  I'm sorry if that confuses you.

Comment: your assertion is wrong : "You can't really do ". people who read  this understand what they read... or he defenitly can do it. the way you write your sentence make a wrong sense. Iwould have siad : yes you can, you have to write the function but you can, by copying once or twice a part of the content of the file (not necessary the hole file epending of the method he choose).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to insert text in line 5 :

1- copy the content of the line 5 to the end of the file on a new file of to a buffer.

2- then write your line. (ater putting cursor in beinnin of line 5)

3- then copy back the lines from the other file.

---

or, more complicated  (not using buffer): (same algorithm as insertion in an array)

you can move all lines atfer the line you want to overwrite to get the eact spae oryour line. then write your line.

for example, you want to write 20 char in line 5.

start by writing 21 char at the end of the file. (if there is a functionthe move charsby 21 characers,i would be easier and perfect).

then put a loop which replace each char with the char in position -21. until un arrive to line 5.
then write your line in line 5.

is that ok ?

Answer (score 0):

The code will look like this:

```
InputFile.open();
tmpFile.open();

while(InputFile.readline())
{
   if (this is where you want the new line)
   {
        tmpFile.write(newLine);
        if(Want to keep the original line)
        {
            tmpFile.writeLine(oldLine);
        }
   }
   else
   {
        tmpFile.writeLine(oldLine);
   }
}

InputFile.close();
tmpFile.close();
unlink(InputFile);
move tmpFile to InputFile.
```